# JCL : How to import xls from FTP location and send email as attachment

Tags: mainframe, jcl

Using JCL I have tried to import  .xls from FTP location into mainframe file . And I have used mainframe file as attachment in email. But in attachment the xls file haveing garbage value .

I have tried receiving file  in binary , text ,ASCII it's not working .

Or

Is there any chance if we receive .zip from FTP to mainframe and send that zip file  as email attachment .

Someone please provide me samples cases

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Saying you're "using JCL" tell nobody anything.  Surely you know that JCL only sets up datasets etc for each step of a job.  You need to tell us what PROCs or PGMs the steps of the JCL are doing.  If you're going to solve it, or expect us to, you need to be able to describe what's in the "mainframe file" after your FTP step.  What recfm etc did you FTP the file into on the mainframe?  What does it look like if you open it in ispf edit?   If it comes to that, have you also looked that at the .xls file on a PC using a hex editor?  Is it mainly plain text or is a binary format?